# i need to encrypt files using a variant of Vernam Cipher in C language. Could you inspect my code?

Tags: c, algorithm, encryption

i'm coding this program that allows you to encrypt files using vernam cipher in C language. i would be glad if you could inspect my code and tell me if i can make some improvements to it or if there are any error.

The request they gave me is:

*The goal is to develop a simple application that allows you to encrypt files using a variant of the Vernam cipher, here called bvernan. The proposed algorithm exploits a simple property of the binary operator XOR: (A XOR B) XOR B = A Given a sequence of k-bytes b0 ... bk-1 (called key), the encoding function of a sequence of bytes d0 ... dN, the encoding / decoding function follows the following simple procedure. The sequence d0 ... dN is first divided into N / k blocks (integer division), D0, ..., D [(N / k) -1] each of which consists of exactly k bytes (apart from the 'last sequence which, obviously, may contain a smaller number of bytes). Subsequently each sequence Dj = dj, 0 ... dj, k-1 is transformed into the sequence D'j = d'j, 0 ... d'j, k-1 such that for each i: d'j, i = b (j + i) mod k XOR dj, i That is, the byte in position i of block j is placed in XOR with the byte (j + i) mod k of the key. The output sequence will then be obtained from the juxtaposition of the sequences D'0, ..., D '[(N / k) -1].*

This is the code:

///file main.c

```
#include "encode.h"

int main (int argc ,char** argv){
    if(argc!=4){
        printf("Usage: bvernan keyfile inputfile outputfile \n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    Key_t* key=openKey(argv[1]);
    
    Register_t* file=openFile(argv[2],argv[3],key->lenght);
    encode(file,key);
    closeRegister(file);
    freeKey(key);
    printf("Success!\n");
}
```

///file encode.c

```
#include "encode.h"

int encode (Register_t* file, Key_t* key ){
    while(readF(file)>0){
        encodeDivision(file->buffer,file->bufferLenght,key);
        writeF(file);
    }
}
void encodeDivision (unsigned char* block,long lenght,Key_t*key){
    for(int i=0;i<lenght;i++){
        block[i]=block[i]^key->buffer[i];
    }
}
```

///file encode.h

```
#include "key.h"
#include "register.h"

int encode (Register_t* file, Key_t* key );
void encodeDivision (unsigned char* block,long lenght,Key_t*key);
```

///file key.c

```
#include "key.h"
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>


long keySize (FILE* file){
    fseek (file,0,SEEK_END);
    long size=ftell(file);
    rewind (file);
    return size;
}
Key_t* openKey(char* path){
    Key_t* kFile= malloc (sizeof(Key_t));
    FILE*file= fopen(path,"rb");
    kFile->lenght=keySize(file);
    kFile->buffer= malloc(kFile->lenght);
    fread(kFile->buffer,1,kFile->lenght,file);
    fclose(file);
    return kFile;
}
void freeKey (Key_t* key ){
free (key->buffer);
free (key);
}
```

/// file key.h

```
typedef struct Key
{
    unsigned char* buffer; 
    long lenght;
} Key_t; 

Key_t* openKey(char* path);
void freeKey (Key_t*);
```

/// file register.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "register.h"

Register_t* openFile (char* inPath,char* outPath,long bufferLenght){
    Register_t* file = malloc (sizeof(Register_t));
    file->buffer= malloc(bufferLenght);
    file->bufferLenght=bufferLenght;
    file->fdIn= fopen(inPath,"rb");
    file->fdOut= fopen(outPath,"wb");
    if(file->fdOut==NULL || file->fdIn==NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
        return file;
}
int readF (Register_t* file){
    int readbyte = fread(file->buffer,1,file->bufferLenght,file->fdIn);
    file->bufferLenght=readbyte;
    return readbyte;
}
int writeF (Register_t* file){
    int writebyte = fwrite(file->buffer,1,file->bufferLenght,file->fdOut);
    return writebyte;
}
void closeRegister (Register_t* file){
    free(file->buffer);
    fclose(file->fdIn);
    fclose(file->fdOut);
    free(file);
}
```

/// file register.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Register
{
    unsigned char *buffer;
    FILE *fdIn;
    FILE *fdOut;
    long bufferLenght;
} Register_t;

Register_t *openFile(char *inPath, char *outPath, long bufferLenght);
int readF(Register_t *);
int writeF(Register_t *);
void closeRegister(Register_t *);
```

/// file Makefile

```
all: bvernan    

bvernan: encode.o key.o main.o register.o
    gcc -o bvernan $^

%.o: %.c
    gcc -c $<

clean:
    rm *.o bvernan
```

Comment: I can tell that it is poorly indented. Start from fixing that.

Comment: If the code works and you're looking for advice on improving it, [codereview.se] is the appropriate place. But see https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users first.

Comment: Does it work as expected?  If so you should post this on codereview.stackexchange.com.  If not, show the input, expected output, and actual output.

Comment: Please focus your question on a specific problem you observe with your code. (Basically same as 2 comments above, but approaching from the other side.)

Comment: so wrong section? sorry guys

Comment: Hint: A Vernam cipher is called a stream cipher in modern cryptography.  A simple, though obsolete, stream cipher is RC4.  You may be able to get some ideas to simplify your program from that.

Answer (score 0):

The program has some problems:

- it is badly presented: you should indent it properly and use spaces wisely.
- it has poor error handling: you will have undefined behavior in most error cases.
- it is much too complicated for the task.

Here is a simpler alternative:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *key, *in, *out;
    int c, x;

    if (argc != 4) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: bvernan keyfile inputfile outputfile\n");
        return 2;
    }
    if ((key = fopen(argv[1], "rb")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "bvernan: cannot open key file %s: %s\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    if ((x = getc(key)) == EOF) {
        fprintf(stderr, "key file is empty\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if ((in = fopen(argv[2], "rb")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "bvernan: cannot open input file %s: %s\n", argv[2], strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    if ((out = fopen(argv[3], "rb")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "bvernan: cannot open output file %s: %s\n", argv[3], strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    rewind(key);
    while ((c = getc(in)) != EOF) {
        if ((x = getc(key)) == EOF) {
            rewind(key);
            x = getc(key);
        }
        putc(c ^ x, out);
    }
    fclose(key);
    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);
    printf("Success!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: could you also give me a better explanation of your code